# Resizing a div using css/html, but there's a catch

Tags: css, html, resize

A page I'm working on has a div that spans its width. Its height has to resize according to the browser window. Here's how I've got it so far:

`#vid_window{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    height:57%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}`

At the bottom of the page is a 'menu' to play an assortment of videos in the above div, and the video, of course, will have to resize with the height of the div. The div is absolutely positioned, per the client. That's not a problem:

`#vid{width:100%;height:100%:}`

As it will fill `#vid_window`

Here's the problem: When the browser page resizes, it doesn't take long for the 'menu' to begin overlapping the vid window. I know I can reduce the percentage, but, I *may* not, per the client. They want the lion's share of the page to be able to display the video, but they, of course, don't want the menu to overlap the window or the vid.

Here's the question: Is there a way to have the vid_window and vid resize exponentially according to the browser window, such that if the window is fully expanded, the vid_window is at 57%, but if it's half-size, the vid_window would be, say, 30%?

Here's a link to the page, if you'd like:

[page](http://adambombdesign.com/enginethree/)

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, it sounds like you'd be better off absolutely positioning the menu at the bottom, and using relative postioning on `vid_window`. With a little JavaScript you can resize it correctly, and it should resolve your overlap issue. If you're allowed to use it, you can make quick work of it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Like James says the best way I can think of for you to do this is set a class on the Div vid_window set the height % in the class and check the display window size to determine your optimal settings.  Also I would probably set a min-height so that the page won't go below that height and for backwards compatibility look at Modernizr. **http://www.modernizr.com/**

------**EDIT**------

That the Header and footer will never be off of the page.  One way to reduce the problems you are having is setting the height on the header and footer to percentages so that they will scale with the height of the body

```
html,body { height:99%; min-height: 100%; }
header { height:22%; min-height: 100px; }
#content { height: 56%; min-height: 200px; }
footer { height:21%; min-height: 100px; }
```

The min-height values can be whatever you think is appropriate for the smallest height you want to go.  The percentage heights on the rest should auto scale you header footer and consequently your content.  This will however force the footer to go off the page at a certain point (when all min widths are met and the browser window continues to shrink).  I do think that this would be desirable and should meet your clients needs. If not then you are going to get into a very complicated javascript that is not always going to do the math just right because of how each browser handles padding and height calculations. On top of that if they disable javascript then it would never work.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the client also wants the top of the vid window to be absolutely positioned, as well, such that the bottom of the vid window collapses upward on browser resize. A thought: Is there a way to create an algorithm that will resize the vid window in relation to the browser's height? Or am I going down the rabbit hole, here? Oh, this is a WordPress site, too...

Comment: you shouldn't have to absolutely position the element to get it to collapse from the bottom up it should do that by default, however if you wanted to the bottom to remain in the same location then absolute positioning may be necessary.  I am not familiar with wordpress or PHP but my recommendation is that if the client doesn't mind drop a couple of javascript or jQuery files in there and check the window size to create an algorithm that will resize to 57% of the display area. finally when you do a jQuery $(window).height() make sure to setTimeout so that it doesn't fire for every pixel.

Comment: As for the bottom-up collapse, I see. The problem is that when the window is expanded, the top and bottom represent 43% of the page, leaving the remaining 57% for the vid window. But when the window is resized, the percentage taken up by the top and bottom goes up (because they are fixed heights,) but the vid window continues to shrink proportionally at 57%, thus the overlap. So, this: If, the top and bottom take up, say, 60% of the browser window, is there a way to ensure the vid window would take up only 40%? Then 70/30, 80/20, etc.

Comment: My client is, to say the least, very exacting. Fixed header and footer. Basically, he wants the video area to be the only area to resize in any fashion. What I did was use absolute positioning and top:#px and bottom:#px. Seems to work just fine. Now, I have to figure out (probably with jQuery) how to proportionally size the video inside the vid window. As for those who disabled js, I'm not going to be too worried about that. It's a very niche site, and likely for people who will need to have their js enabled to view many sites they're interested in. Thanks for your input.